# Fourier transform of integral function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

A function $s(t)$ is defined by
$s(t)=\int_x p(t-cx)dx$
where $\tau = cx$ is a time variable and $t\neq \tau$. What is the Fourier transform, $S(\omega)$, of the function $s(t)$?

I know that for a function $f(t)=g(t-cx)$, the Fourier transform would be $F(\omega)=e^{i\omega cx}G(\omega)$, where $G(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $g(t)$. However, I don't think I can say that
$S(\omega)=P(\omega)\int_x e^{i\omega cx} dx$.

Comment: It almost looks like a convolution of $1$ with $p$ so my guess is $\delta(\omega) P(\omega)$ times some constant, which is what you wrote.

Comment: Ah good spot! Thank you very much :)